how to access a django project when we are in the same network?
As you know, you can check django application by running this command:
python3 manage.py runserver

Let's say, there are 2 laptop which are sharing same internet network. When i run server for django app, i can access it on my browser from this address:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/

But i would like to know if it is possible to access from another computer? I tried the same address but I could not access.
My development stack is;
Django version => 4.2.4
Python version => 3.11

How can i solve this issue?
I tried to access from another laptop which sharing same network. i could not access.
PS: I did not understand why my question is deleted. I saw some answers about this about the answers were very old like 6-14 years ago and development tech stacks were not the same. This questions should not be deleted. Also, I cannot approve the answers because of reputations. It does not make sense!

127.0.0.1 is your local loopback address. It's always your own computer. To access it from another computer, you need to use your computer's IP on the local network, which probably looks something like 10.x.x.x.

Run
 python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0 8000

then on the other PC
http://YOUR_PC_IP:8000/

Make sure that the firewall allows communication on port TCP 8000
also, add your IP to ALLOWED_HOSTS in the settings.py
